# Changing the shape of a animation inserted in an image, inserted in a video sequence

Tags: animation, 2d, distort

(I am a newbie, working hard at learning) I know what I want but don't know how to start to get it.
I have a 2d animation I have created and put over the top of a still image, that I want to use in a video sequence.
I have figured out how to get to this point but I need to change the form of the inner movie clip to look like it is happening inside a locker on a boat. Narrow the base of its rectangle.
http://www.mapleton.net.au/temp/shark-locker.mkv
What is the direction of learning I need to get there? I'm a bit lost.

[image]

Comment: Drop us a screenshot.

Comment: I added a screenshot but neglected to tell you!